# Obstacle course and line intersection

Tags: algorithms

In my computer class I'm learning about computational geometry and I have a problem to solve but can't understand how to get to the solution.

Imagine I have a $10$ by $10$ board and on top of that board, I have a ball in a position, let's say $(5,0)$ being $5$ the $x$ coordinate and $0$ the $y$ coordinate.

On that board I have some obstacles (line segments). Imagine in the given example I have this three line segments:

Obstacle A: Line segment formed by the points $(4,1)$ and $(6,2)$

Obstacle B: Line segment formed by the points $(2,5)$ and $(7,3)$

Obstacle C: Line segment formed by the points $(1,6)$ and $(3,7)$

So, the ball departs from coordinate $(5,0)$ in vertical direction. It then intersects with $Obstacle A$ and since this line segment as as an "inclination" to the right, it arrives at the $(6,2)$ coordinates and drops vertically from that position. Now, the ball keeps falling and intersects with $Obstacle B$ and since it as an left "inclination", the ball arrives at the $(2,5)$ coordinate. Again, it drops vertically at $(2,5)$ coordinate and intersects $Obstacle C$. This obstacle as an right "inclination" so the ball goes to $(3,7)$ and drops. Since there are no more obstacles, the ball drops vertically and arrives at the end of the board at the $(3,10)$ coordinate.

I have to develop an algorithm, to given the position of the ball and the positions of the line segments, find the $x$ coordinate were the ball arrives at the end of the board.

I came across the line intersection problem, were we sweep lines from sorted increasing $x$ coordinate.

I don't know if I can use that approach because the direction of the ball is not fixed. For example, in the line intersection problem, we would process the $Obstacle C$ and see that it does not intersect with the ball but after the ball hits the first obstacles it then intersects with the $Obstacle C$.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the obstacles doesn't intersect with each other. We'll form a directed graph from this given problem and convert the problem to finding an endpoint of a path.

The construction of the graph is as follows. We consider each obstacle line segment as an edge and its endpoints as vertices. If it is right (left) inclined the direction of this edge is left to right (right to left). Now, think like you are shooting a ray from  one of the endpoints of the obstacles. It'll hit another obstacle above it or it will hit the $10^{th}$ row. To simulate this action we add one vertical edge from right (left) endpoint of any right (left) inclined edge. We can check the intersection points of the ray and other line segments and take the line segment $l$ with least y-coordinate of intersection point. The vertical edge is having this intersection point $p$ as its other vertex. Note, that we split the the edge of $l$ into two from $p$ keeping the directions same. If the vertical ray doesn't get blocked by any other obstacles and touches the $10^{th}$ row then the top vertex of the corresponding edge is having y-coordinate 10. See the figure for your example.

[image: Example graph]

Now given the start point we add one more edge to the graph which simulates the vertical ray shooting from it. It also split the intersecting edge (if any) to two.

After constructing the graph we can just traverse the path until we reach to an edge from where there is no way out. As the graph would be acyclic this argument works. The top endpoint of that edge is our solution.